# Http server in Ubuntu is not reachable in same network

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, lan

My laptop and phone is connected to home network.

laptop_ip: 192.168.1.8

phone_ip: 192.168.1.2

when I ping 192.168.1.2 from my laptop, it's OK and ping is successful. But when I type 192.168.1.8 in my phone's browser, I cannot load apache2 default page. This address is accessible when I type it in my laptop's browser.

I have both windows and ubuntu and I switched to my Windows and started a http server in my windows and tried to access it from my phone and I was successful. So my modem and router is OK I think. and the problem is with my ubuntu. but what? I DON'T KNOW. PLEASE HELP ME. TNX

Comment: It "my http server" configured to accept connections from "my phone"? It might just listen on my localhost be default.

Comment: Pinging is not the same as accessing a web server. If I understand you correctly, you have one machine with dual boot, and installed on each OS an apache server, with windows you can access but with ubuntu not, that's correct? If this is the case, it may be that there's somenthing in your apache configuration that is different in both servers.

Comment: On Ubuntu try to temporary disable firewall `sudo ufw disable`.

Comment: @mikewhatever it's listening on 0.0.0.0

Comment: @guillermochamorro I tried python3 -m http.server that is listening on 0.0.0.0:8000. But it's not working too on ubuntu. It's Ok on windows. And yes, they are dual boot, not virtual

Comment: @michalPrzybylowicz It's disabled by default. I tried `sudo ufw status` and it's disabled

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz My ufw was disabled, but iptables rules was rejected that request. who is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you duel booting?  Is that how you are testing your windows web server?  If you're doing something like a virtual machine (e.g. VirtualBox), answers might be different.

Back on your linux server, type the following command:

```
sudo netstat -tlnp
```

This will show you all ports that are either waiting for connections or already connected.

You can use `grep` to filter to port 80 thusly:

```
sudo netstat -tlnp | grep 80
```

If port 80 is indeed open, but you still can't access the web server, see if the web server is receiving traffic at all by running tcpdump:

```
sudo tcpdump 'port 80'
```

Leave that window open and then visit your server.  If the prompt doesn't move, something is blocking your connection.  You may have a firewall or something blocking your connection.

If it does move, provide the output and we can investigate further.

Comment: My windows and ubuntu is installed dual boot, not virtual

Comment: What happens when you run the last command and visit the website?

Comment: This message is what I see

`01:05:42.223104 IP 192.168.1.2.52091 > hamed.8000: Flags [S], seq 3110608520, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4958321 ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0`

Comment: That was because of a rule in my iptables:( sorry.